# FontAwesome icon in Sass with Webpack is not displayed

Tags: webpack, sass, font-awesome

I have a problem in FontAwesome in Sass with Webpack.

I tried to use `$fa-var-twitter` provided by FontAwesome at a class in Sass like the below. I expected the `.twitter` to display the Twitter icon, but it was not correctly displayed. it was displayed the shape of an empty square. However, Webpack does not put an error message, which means the build seems successful.

```
.twitter {
  @extend %fa-icon;
  @extend .fab;
  margin-right: 10px;
  &:before {
    content: fa-content($fa-var-twitter);
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #d9534f;
  }
}
```

After building, I checked `@font-face` at built CSS file from Sass. It seems something wrong in that the part of the `url` was not replaced with the value of `$fa-font-path` that I defined in Sass file. The wrong path looks `../node_modules` like the below.

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-display:block;src:url("../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
}
```

The following are my Webpack settings.

**webpack.config.js**

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: './webfonts',
            }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
```

**index.js**

```
// Fontawesome for SASS tag
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2';

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2';

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2';

import './style.scss';
```

**style.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: "./webfonts";

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
```

Please tell me how to solve the issue.
Thanks.